# Are Follow Rules sufficient/correct?

Tags: context-free-grammar

There are the usual FIRST-rules 1..5 and the usual FOLLOW-rules 1..5 (known to me), but they don't seem sufficient to me. My question is, if I am wrong, and they are in fact sufficient, or if I am correct, and they really need to be augmented by one or two more rules, especially when recursion comes into play. If the latter holds, there are probably still grammatical cases I didn't think of. Point of origin for my thoughts is the elimination of left-recursion and the (known to me) rules for generating FOLLOW-Sets.

I am sure that FOLLOW-rules should be augmented by rules 6 & 7.

I am unsure about rule 8.
The rules for generating FIRST-Sets seem pretty complete to me, even with recursion.

rule 1

```
If A -> βB, and β is a Terminal, then FIRST(A) U β
```

rule 2.

```
If A -> Ɛ, then FIRST(A) U Ɛ
```

rule 3.

```
If A -> Bβ, then add FIRST(B) - {e} to FIRST(A)
```

rule 4.

```
If A -> B_0, B_1, B_2...BiB+1...B_k; and (B_0..B_i) are nullable;

  4.1 then add FIRST(B_i) - {e} to FIRST(A)
```

rule 5.

```
If A -> B_0, B_1, B_2...BiB+1...B_k; and (B_0..B_k) are nullable

5.1 then add FIRST(B_k) to FIRST(A)

5.2 then add {e} to FIRST(A)
```

### FOLLOW Rules

The FIRST-rules are about what a NonTerminal can derive. The FOLLOW-rules in contrast are about *where* a NonTerminal appears in the productions.

The usual rules (known to me) to generate the FOLLOW set are

rule 1.

```
If S is the starting symbol of the grammar, then add {§} to FOLLOW(S)
```

rule 2.

```
If A -> β B, add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(B) <Special case of 4 and 5. (May be omitted.?)>
```

rule 3.

```
If A -> B, C_0, C_1, C_2... C_k, and epsilon is not element of C_0 .. C_k, then add FIRST(C_0) to FOLLOW(A)
```

rule 4.

```
If A -> B, C_0, C_1, C_2 ...C_i, C_+1, ... C_k, and epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_0), and epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_1), and epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_2), and... epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_i), then add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(C_i+1)
```

rule 5.

```
If A -> B, C_0, C_1, C_2 ...C_i, C_+1, ... C_k, and epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_0), and epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_1), and epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_2), and... epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_k), then add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(B)
```

Conjecture:

If the rules so far are correct (esp. the one about eliminated left-recursion), Wouldn't FOLLOW-Set rules 5 and 6 of have to be augmented

a) By a recursive rule for productions like C -> dC | Ɛ

rule 6. In case of eliminated left-recursion:

```
 i.  A  -> D B'
ii.  B' -> α D B' 
iii. B' -> Ɛ
iv.  D  -> E D'
v.  ...
```

where α may be a string of Terminals and Nonterminals but which begins with a Terminal

then

6.1 [to ii.]

```
add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(D)
```

6.2 [to iii.]

```
add α to FOLLOW(D)
```

6.3 [to iv.]

```
add FOLLOW(D) to FOLLOW(E)
```

6.4
...

b) By following rule where a NonTerminal appears on the rhs of a production:

rule 7.

```
If A -> '(' B ')', then add ')' to FOLLOW(B)
```

c) by the following rule, after which it is not only the last NonTerminal in a row of nullable NonTerminal symbols that should be added to the according FOLLOW-Set.

rule 8.

```
If A -> alpha B, C_0, C_1, C_2 ...C_i, C_i+1, ... C_k, and (C_0..C_i) are nullable, then
```

8.1

```
add FIRST(C_0) - {epsilon} to FOLLOW(B)   U add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(C_0)
```

8.2

```
add FIRST(C_1) - {epsilon} to FOLLOW(C_0) U add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(C_1)
```

8.3

```
add 

FIRST(C_2) - {epsilon} to FOLLOW(C_1) U add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(C_2)
    ...
```

8.4

```
add FIRST(C_i+1) - {epsilon} to FOLLOW(C_i) U add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(C_i+1)
```

rule 9.

```
If A -> alpha B, C_0, C_1, C_2 ...C_i, C_+1, ... C_k; and (C_0..C_k) are nullable,
```

then

```
9.1. proceed as in <8>

9.2 add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(B)
```

### Explanation:

**Statement 1:**

In Rule 8 for example, epsilon ∈ FIRST(C_0) means that the NonTerminal can expand to epsilon - but mustn'd!
As long as we have such NonTerminals that can expand to epsilon, these constitute a **nullable row** from left to right                                                                                                                                                        which is **ended** by either one of two possible cases:

1. by a NonTerminal "C_last_non_epsilon" where epsilon is **not** ∈ of FIRST(C_last_non_epsilon).

-- or --

2. when it is the case that the whole row ("nullable row") of NonTerminals of the right-hand-side of the production is nullable. Then the last element, let's call it "C_last_nullable" consequentially is also nullable and is still canonically **considered the last element.**

**Statement 1.2:**

Regardless, for both cases of **last elements** the following rule holds:

1. Add the FOLLOW-Set of the right-hand-side of the production to the FOLLOW-Set of said last element.

**Statement 2: Every nullable NT can be the last**

But this is the pivot point: The canonical set of rules (as known to me) only considers as last NonTerminal that which does not derive epsilon. But as we stated before, nullable NonTerminals can potentially be nulled out - **but must not actually be so.** Theoretically though, every nullable NonTerminal however **could be the last one.**

Also it holds, such as stated above, in contrast to the FIRST Set, the FOLLOW-Set is about **where** in in a production the NT is.

Wouldn't the logical consequence then be rules (5.1..5.5) and (6.1..6.2) ? Namely that we would have to add, this time **from right to left**, the **FIRST-Set (without epsilon) of any NonTerminal of the "nullable row" to the FOLLOW-Set of the nullable NonTerminal immediately to the left of it** ?

As the FOLLOW-Set of the production-lhs would be added to the FOLLOW-Set of the **last NonTerminal (which cannot derive epsilon)**, but as every NonTerminal from the **"nullable row"** could possibly good be the **last NonTerminal**, shouldn't this rule then too apply to every NonTerminal from the **"nullable row"** simply ?

**By the same reasoning I think rule 8 holds.**

If it is correct so far, wouldn't the FOLLOW-Set of nullable NTs then have to grow from right to left, such that the most left nullable NonTerminal
would have the largest FOLLOW-Set?

But if the reasoning is wrong, then obviously rule 8 as consequence is wrong and so is the consequence of latter paragraph.

And I think there is a proof by contradiction that the reasoning is wrong. As should be clear now, a nullable NonTerminal is only
*potentially* nullable. It can *potentially* derive epsilon and therefore it has epsilon in it's FIRST-Set. Rules 4 and 5 assume that the nullable NonTerminals are not only *potentially nullable* but *factually nulled* by rules 4 & 5. But that's only an assumption. It could just as well factually **not derive epsilon,** but could derive something else. Now that would alter the "nullable row" and consequentially our rule 8. It would alter the FOLLOW-Set: If the **last NonTerminal** is further left, by our logic, the FOLLOW-Set of the most left NTs and the following NTs would be (much) smaller. **Theres a contingency.**

**On the other hand, doesn't this contingency also hold for rules 4 & 5 ?**

It presents like both contradictory rules, namely rules 4 & 5 on one side, and rule 8 on the other side, are justifiable, which can't be.

Answer (score 0):

A terminal `a` is in the follow set for non-terminal `A` if and only if the grammar can derive from the starting symbol a sentential form which includes `Aa`. That's it. It's not a very complicated concept. (In fact, calling it the "follow set" precisely describes it: *a* ∈ FOLLOW(*A*) if *a* follows a sequence of input symbols which are parsed as *A*.)

You can efficiently compute follow sets for a grammar by using a transitive closure algorithm, and that's the way most parser generators work. But for whatever reason, most textbooks instead teach the least fixed-point algorithm. Maybe it's easier to understand. But regardless, the definition of the follow set is as above.

There are precisely two circumstances in which the symbol *a* can follow the non-terminal *A*.

First, the *a* could be the first symbol in an expansion of the part of some production's right-hand side which immediately follows *A*. So there is some production `T → αAβ` where `a ∈ FIRST(β)`. (Note that β here is an arbitrary sequence of grammar symbols, and that the FIRST set of a sequence of grammar symbols is precisely the set of tokens which might start an expansion of that sequence.)

[**Note:** It's usual to add ε to a FIRST set if the symbol (or sequence) could produce the empty sequence ε. There are good reasons for that convention which I'm not going to go into but it can also be confusing because it makes it look like ε is a grammar symbol, because all the other elements in a FIRST set are grammar symbols. But ε isn't a grammar symbol; it's an empty sequence of grammar symbols. I'm avoiding that confusion here by explicitly saying "can expand to an empty sequence" (i.e. "is nullable") rather than "ε ∈ FIRST".]

Second, the non-terminal *A* might be at the effective end of the right-hand side of some production for a different non-terminal *B*. In that case, the follow set of *A* also includes any symbol in the follow set of *B*. By "effective end", I mean that whatever follows the non-terminal in the right-hand side could possibly expand to nothing. (A non-terminal might well be the effective end of a recursive production for itself. But that doesn't have any effect on follow sets; saying that the follow set of *A* also includes the follow set of *A* is an obvious tautology.)

So there are exactly two rules (although you can write them with special cases if you want more rules :-). We scan every right-hand side of every production (in any order which is convenient, which may well be right-to-left). At each position `T → αAβ` (where α and β are possibly empty sequences of symbols and `A` is a non-terminal):

1. Add every terminal in FIRST(β) to FOLLOW(A).
2. If β can produce the empty sequence (i.e. β is empty or consists only of nullable non-terminals), add FOLLOW(T) to FOLLOW(A).

But we can't just do this scan once. We have to keep on doing it until all the sets are saturated. In other words, we keep doing scans until an entire scan of all the rules adds no new elements to any follow set. (It's really only necessary to apply the first rule on the first scan, since nothing changes on subsequent scans. However, that assumes that the FIRST sets have already been computed. We could, however, compute FIRST sets at the same time as we compute FOLLOW sets, using a similar set of rules, in which case both the FIRST and the FOLLOW sets might change in a single scan.)

Comment: What's with the case under "rule 6": `B' -> α D B' ` - cannot α follow D here?

Comment: Also we could omit the tautology `add FOLLOW(B') to FOLLOW(B')` in this special case.

Comment: (1) `B` → αDB'`  certainly does not say that α follows D.  D follows α, but we don't care: we're only interested in seeing which terminals follow which non-terminals and D isn't a terminal. (2) Yes, adding FOLLOW(B') to FOLLOW(B') is an obvious no-op. But we don't need extra special case rules to avoid that.

Comment: But rici, if the `B'` at the end in `B' -> αDB'` expands to `αDB'` then of course α follows D

1.`B' -> αDB'`
2. `B' -> αDαDB'`

Comment: One could generalize for recursive rules, that, where the lhs-NT is also at the end of the rhs, if FIRST(α) contains a Terminal, then add the first Terminal in α to FOLLOW(D).

But this again is a question of actuality/potentiality. Again      `B' -> αDB'` **mustn'd** expand to `B' -> αDαDB'`, just like in FOLLOW-rules 4 & 5 the nullable NTs **can** but **mustn'd** be nulled out.

Comment: Why must they not be nullified? I think you are overcomplicating something which is really very simple.

Comment: Also: α is not a grammar symbol. The fact that FIRST(B') is included in FOLLOW(D) is already accomplished in the first of my two rules. Again, no special case is needed.

Comment: Would you be ok with moving this discussion into chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225001/discussion-between-rici-and-von-spotz).

Comment: @von: I responded to the chat. But I'm heading out now and won't be back for several hours.